# Finding coefficient of a term in power series expansion of some function

Tags: series-expansion

Say I have a function like $\dfrac{1}{(1+x)^2}$ and I wish to find the coefficient of $x^{300}$ if the above function is expanded about $x=0$. Is there a command in Mathematica for this?

Using the command below doesn't seem to be fine with me, for it calculates all the terms till $300$ and is so infeasible. Is there a simpler way?

`Series[1/(1+x)^2,{x,0,30}]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SeriesCoefficient[1/(1 + x)^2, {x, 0, 300}]
```

> 301

```
SeriesCoefficient[1/(1 + x)^2, {x, 0, n}]
```

> $\begin{cases} 
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  (-1)^n (n+1) & n\geq 0 \\
>  0 & \text{True} \\
> \end{array} 
> \end{cases}$

Comment: In current versions, you can even use `D[]` with symbolic order directly.